# Referer и JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, get

К примеру, через JS я делаю запрос к стороннему сайту:

```
$.getJSON('http://site.ru/test.php', {

}, function(data) {
 alert(data);
});
```

К коду стороннего сайта я доступ не имею. И у меня вопрос:

> При вызове этого скрипта с моего
> сайта, на сайте
> http://site.ru/test.php можно
> посмотреть, откуда пришёл запрос
> (HTTP_REFERER). Можно ли как-то
> сделать так, что когда я передаю
> запрос на чужой сайт через JS, **referer** не
> палился? На php например можно скрыть referer с помощью CURL, а в JS как?

Comment: в интернете пишут, что никак, но какой в этом смысл, если владелец сервера наверняка так или иначе знает, кому он предоставляет CORS-доступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно, это ведь обычный заголовок запроса. Отправляйте запрос не `$.getJSON`, а `$.ajax`-ом, ответ обрабатывайте на `success`:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://test-site.ru",
         data: { key: value },
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Referer', 'lalala');},
         success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); }
      });
```

Comment: > Конечно можно, это ведь обычный заголовок запроса.

![Опа-па](http://i.imgur.com/JYEA5z9.png)

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/7ZugDEgQ)  
[handler.php](http://pastebin.com/qmUsazQq)

по-моему, довольно очевидно, что ни один браузер по ясным причинам не даст подменять реферер.

Comment: > по-моему, довольно очевидно, что ни один браузер по ясным причинам не даст подменять реферер.

Согласен, мой первоначальный ответ неверный, referer не подделается, но ничто не мешает немного изменить код следующим образом:

`index.php`:
http://pastebin.com/tjwzKEfu

`send-fake-referer.php`:
http://pastebin.com/ujgQgJ8U

Comment: Ну, автор в курсе существования cURL, я так понял что ему нужно исключительно клиентское решение.